# Customize JIRA for a hierarchical workflow model

Tags: jira-agile

What is the data model for an issue in JIRA for software projects? Is the hierarchy as follows - project->epics->stories->subtasks?

I want to create a Project management board with multiple stages . In this project, you can proceed to the next stage on only completing the earlier stages.

I wanted to create a 2-level hierarchy of workflows where the epics are in one workflow and the stories have their own workflow. Hence, there will be two boards

- one showing the status of the epics in their workflow and
- another
  showing the status of the stories/tasks in their workflow

Is it possible to customize JIRA to allow this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about JIRA boards is that they are simply views on issues. [This means you can define what shows up on boards using JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile063/jira-agile-user-s-guide/creating-a-board).

As an example, you could have a workflow for epics and then a board to show this workflow using a JQL that is something like this:

> project = "myproject" and type = epic

Then you define a different workflow for your stories and show them on a different board using a JQL like this:

> project = "myproject" and type = story

This means that even though the epics and stories both exist in the same project they can still be shown on different boards and with different workflows.

Comment: How do I add the biz logic in the JIRA project - "you can proceed to the next stage on only completing the earlier stages". I know JIRA is a scrum team tool, so it inherently is breaking fundamental agile values. However, I am trying to define a kanban workflow where a set of tasks need to be completed before the next set of tasks can begin. I want to implement this biz rule in my board.

Comment: Probably best to ask this as a new stackoverflow question. It's difficult to answer this well in a comment!

Comment: Yep, sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263232/jira-setup-project-constraints