# JIRA setup - project constraints so that tasks need to be completed before next set of tasks can begin

Tags: jira-agile, agile-project-management

How do I add the business logic in a JIRA project where you can proceed to the next stage on only completing the earlier stages.

I am aware that JIRA is a Agile scrum team tool, so it inherently is breaking fundamental agile principles. However, I am trying to define a Kanban workflow where a set of tasks needs to be completed before the next set of tasks can begin. I want to implement this business rule in my JIRA board.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal solution, but one approach is to use sub-tasks.

It is possible to add a [condition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/advanced-workflow-configuration-776636620.html#Advancedworkflowconfiguration-conditions) so that an issue cannot be transitioned unless all it's sub-tasks are completed.

Comment: Okay. So Is there a way to add that to a story that has sub-tasks?

Comment: What about adding some branching logic to the stories so that if all the tasks are complete put story A in the task list, if 2 specific tasks of the 3 subtasks are complete put story B in the tasklist. Is that to be done using the OSworkflow in JIRA?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about OSworkflow. Or are you talking about standard JIRA workflows?

Comment: JIRA's workflow editor generates OSWorkflow XML definition files that are stored in JIRA's database - https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/using-xml-to-create-a-workflow-802592824.html

Comment: I was referring to the condition logic that is associated with transitions. I updated my answer to include a link to the Atlassian help page for conditions.